# Effect size + variance calculation single group pretest posttest - different sample size pretest-posttest

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, cohens-d, metafor

I include single group pretest-posttest study designs in my meta-analysis. I calculate the effect size as follows: difference between posttest mean and pretest mean divided by the standard deviation of the pretest mean (Becker et al., 1988). The variance of such an effect sizes depends on the correlation of the pre- and post-test scores and N, the number of pairs.

For most of my data, I have the means and SD for the pairs - N pretest is the same as N posttest.

However, some of my articles report the means and SD for a different sample size. For example pretest N = 64; posttest N = 60.

Now, if I would like to calculate the effect size in R by using the metaphor package function escalc(measure="SMCR"), I have to include mean pretest, mean posttest, standard deviation pretest, N and r(correlation between pre-post) in the function.
Assuming an example as previously illustrated, where my means are derived from not the same group of participants, what would I use for N? The pretest sample size or the posttest sample size? You could probably find suitable arguments for both. It might make more sense to take the pretest sample size, as the standard deviation used to standardize the mean difference is also based on the pretest information (as I use the Becker formula). On the other hand, it could also make sense to take the posttest number, as any paired t-tests in the study (which I often use to calculate the correlation between pre- and post-test, see Morris & DeShon, 2002) are presumably based on the post-test sample size. Probably there is no perfect solution here, as the means that you enter into the function in metaphor should probably come from the same number of participants. However, as I said, that's not always possible with the data that is presented in the articles.
What would be best-practice in such a situation?

Would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your N's are close (even if not exact) then you shouldn't get a significantly different result using either the pre-test or post-test N. You can always run a sensitivity analysis using the other. The issues arises when there is a large loss to follow up, missing data and/ or dropouts. In all cases, document how you managed this issue in your study report.

Comment: @abousetta: Thanks, I appreciate it! Good advice.